# Having the apps in the task bar always in the same order. Open apps on the right of the others

Tags: awesome-wm

I would like to have some apps (which I open when starting my session) always in the same order in the task bar. Is that possible?

```
Vim | Chrome | Terminal
```

Another question: for now, when I open an app, it is opened on the left part of the task bar, is there a way to open it rather on the right side, after the already open apps?

I have this lines in rc.lua:

```
-- Add widgets to the wibox - order matters
mywibox[s].widgets = {
    {
        mylauncher,
        mytaglist[s],
        mypromptbox[s],
        layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.leftright
    },
    mylayoutbox[s],
    mytextclock,
    s == 1 and mysystray or nil,
    mytasklist[s],
    layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
}
```

Javi

Answer (score 2):

To place new windows to the end of the list (make them slave) you can add rule to the rc.lua file

```
{ rule = { }, properties = { }, callback = awful.client.setslave }
```

To autostart apps use

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("App1 -with -keys")
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("App2 -with -keys")
```

They will run in this order I believe. And make sure that you added awful in the rc.lua. You can do it by function require("awful")

[Take a look at the FAQ](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_start_clients_as_slave_windows_instead_of_master.3F)

P.S. Sorry, I'm not sure do I understand you right.